# How to make a File Exists Converter in WinRT

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, converters

I'm trying to check with a converter if a Image Source exists in local storage. If not go with the external url.

`<Image Source="{Binding Image,  Converter={StaticResource ImageCacheConverter}}"/>`

This is my converter so far:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    return IfFileExist((string)value, "localimage.png");
}
public async Task<string> IfFileExist(string value, string filename)
{
    var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var getFilesAsync = await folder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName);

    var file = getFilesAsync.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == filename);
    if (file != null)
    {
        return "ms-appdata:///local/" + filename;
    }
    return (string)value;
}
```

The major problem I'm facing is having async inside an IValueConverter. But i need the return o the IfFileExist to change the image source.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why is `IfFileExist` `async` anyway?

Comment: Cause await folder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName);

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you want a potentially slow operation to be part of a binding? I'd cache the info and add some error handling if the file got moved. There is a reason why this method is `async`!

Comment: I'm trying to check if the image is cached on the local storage. It should be a normal converter work. I'm new to c#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want don't want your `IfFileExist` method to run asychronously. But that's what is happening because of the usage of `await`.

Try changing it to this:

```
public async Task<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Windows.Storage.StorageFile>> GetFilesAsync()
{
    var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    return await folder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName)
                       .AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public string IfFileExist(string value, string filename)   
{   
    var files = GetFilesAsync().Result;

    var file = files.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == filename);   
    if (file != null)   
    {   
        return "ms-appdata:///local/" + filename;   
    }   
    return value;   
}
```

Instead of using `await` we are accessing the `Result` property of the task that is returned by `GetFilesAsync`, blocking our method until the task finished.

Your original code is quasi-equivalent to the following:

```
public async Task<string> IfFileExist(string value, string filename) 
{ 
    var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder; 
    var getFilesAsync = folder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName); 

    return getFilesAsync.ContinueWith(z => 
    {
        var file = getFilesAsync.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == filename); 
        if (file != null) 
        { 
            return "ms-appdata:///local/" + filename; 
        } 
        return (string)value; 
    }
}
```

Comment: the converter returns an error:
The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<object>'

Comment: A got this error:

'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Windows.Storage.StorageFile>>' does not contain a definition for 'Result' and no extension method 'Result' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Windows.Storage.StorageFile>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @nicruo: Please see update. I have no experience with `Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation`, so there might be an easier way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your help but now my app enters GetFilesAsync() but never comes out.

Comment: This solution causes the [deadlock problem I describe here](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: @StephenCleary: Thanks for the link. Fixed the deadlock - I guess.

Comment: One more error: 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Windows.Storage.StorageFile>>' does not contain a definition for 'StartAsTask' and no extension method 'StartAsTask' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Windows.Storage.StorageFile>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @nicruo: You are welcome. Thanks to Stephen I learned quite a lot myself along the way :-)

Comment: Sorry for trolling, but I'm trying to do something similar but am getting an error. Is this not possible with this function?   private async Task<StorageFile> createFileSync(StorageFolder folder, string filename)
  {
    return await folder.CreateFileAsync(filename,
      CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
  }

  private async Task<Stream> openStreamForWriteSync(StorageFile file)
  {
    return await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync().AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
  }

Answer (score 2):

The core problem is that you need to do an `async` operation within a synchronous operation (`Convert`). There isn't an easy way to do this; if possible, structure your code so that it isn't necessary (e.g., have one property kick off an `async` update to another property which is the result of the "conversion").

If you want to try to force it to fit, you have to use `ConfigureAwait(false)`:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
  // Note that "Result" will wrap any errors in AggregateException, which is annoying.
  return IfFileExist((string)value, "localimage.png").Result;
}

public async Task<string> IfFileExist(string value, string filename)
{
  var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
  var getFilesAsync = await folder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName)
      .AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);

  var file = getFilesAsync.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == filename);
  if (file != null)
  {
    return "ms-appdata:///local/" + filename;
  }
  return (string)value;
}
```

Comment: Got this error: 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Windows.Storage.StorageFile>>' does not contain a definition for 'StartAsTask' and no extension method 'StartAsTask' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Windows.Storage.StorageFile>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Thanks man. You lead to the right answer. Daniel Hilgarth nailed it. Sorry I can't pick up you both as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Windows 8 near me right now but I may suggest to try the following code (just `Convert` method body):

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)   
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    Task.Run(async delegate
    {
        result = await IfFileExist((string)value, "localimage.png");
    }).Wait();

    return result;
}
```

I'm not sure if it's working however.

Comment: Hi Alexander, sorry i didn't answer you. I tried it and it didn't work. But thanks for your time anyway.